# How to deploy nodejs/express with their only packages to my server using nrwl/nx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I created two applications in my repo using nx: `myapp-nodejs`, `myapp-angular`. (not nest)

Now, I want to deploy those apps to my server. (I don't want to use nginx to create a route for api and route for static files - let's say I don't want to use nginx anyway).

`myapp-nodejs` application runs `express` and serve the index file.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'));
});
```

So now I need to build those apps, and then copy `myapp-angular` dist to `myapp-nodejs` dist\public folder (for the `sendFile`).

When I try to run the nodejs application in my server it's say I need some packages that in my `package.json` in my root package.

The problem is I'll install unnecessary packages like angular and more that my server don't need them and not belong to nodejs runtime.

So I though if there is a way to know "this are the packages for nodejs"? in json format maybe? so I do script that detect dependencies against the root `package.json` and extract the necessary?

Comment: Maybe show the exact message that you get?

Comment: missing `express` dep because I need to install the express but there is no `package.json` that nx generate for me. So I think they relay on the root package.json in my project, but in this file I also have unnecessary package that client side uses.